# Sharing files between Android mobile and wear modules

Tags: android, android-studio, module, wear-os

Several months ago, I originally started my project with just a mobile module, and now I am interested in configuring my app for wearable devices as well. That said, all of my files (Java, XML, drawables, and etc.) are in the mobile module, so do I need to transfer all of the files I want to share between mobile and wear modules into a newly created "common" module?

**EDIT**:

Can somebody explain to me what the following Gradle project sync errors coming from the mobile and wear's Gradle files mean:

[image]

... This happened after I included ***compile project(':common')*** in both modules as follows:

First, here's my common module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dpark.gameoflife"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

Mobile module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dpark.gameoflife"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile project(':common')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Lastly, my wear module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dpark.gameoflife"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
    compile project(':common')
}
```

... If anything, I signed an APK of my common module in release mode, and yet I get the same errors as shown above.

Comment: There is a long treatment of these questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694206/android-studio-project-that-builds-for-both-wear-os-and-normal-app-but-shares-s/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, If your files are used by both modules (mobile and wear) then obviously, you should make these two modules use a shared module where you put all the necessary files.

in each module add `compile project(': common')`

Comment: Ok, so what kinds of files am I supposed to leave in the mobile and wear modules then besides the Gradle files? Because, I literally transferred all of the files except for the Gradle file from the mobile module to the common module.

Comment: You should transfer common files like drawables, styles or maybe some shared java classes like `utils`, `base activity` or ...
Leave on each module only the specific implementation for this device

Comment: Let's say you're using a recyclerview in both devices, mobile contains a list with two colums and the wear a list with one column.
in this situation, you'll retrieve data from your shared module then display it on mobile with two columns and on wear with one column

Comment: Got it, but apparently I am getting some errors (as shown in my edited post above) when I try to sync my Gradle project after including **_compile project(':common')_** in both the mobile and wear modules... Any idea what the errors mean?

Comment: since your common module is not application (not executable), it only works like a library you should use `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` instead of `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: One more question though: how do you import drawable resource files from the common module by using Java code? Would it look something like **import dpark.common.R;**

Comment: Exactly, that's the way to do it `package name of the common module.R`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html):

1- Make sure the first line in the `build.gradle (Module:my-library-module)`, is defined correctly as:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

2- Add the library to the `settings.gradle` as:

```
include ':app', ':my-library-module'
```

3- Compile the library in the `build.gradle (Module:xxx)`(Module:mobile) as:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":my-library-module")
}
```

4- In your project, `import` the library as:

```
import xxx.xx.xx
```

Comment: The `compile` directive is deprecated.  Currently, the compile line should read
`implementation project(':my-library-module')`